# Joining multiple table using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to join multiple table to join using criteria but getting some problem , please help me:
I have a sql query like :

```
SELECT  a.type, a.time, c.code AS exchangeCode
 FROM   CutOffTime AS a INNER JOIN
       Country AS b ON a.country_fk = b.id INNER JOIN
       Exchange AS c ON c.country_fk = b.id
```

These three table : CutOffTime (has country), Country, Exchange (has country) are 3 entity classes.

How can i join like this using hibernate criteria,my code below still not complete :

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> aa= ( List<Map<String, Object>>) getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {
            @Override
            public Object doInHibernate(final Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                final Criteria c = session.createCriteria(CutOffTime.class,"cutofftime");
                c.createAlias("cutofftime.country", "country");

                final Criteria c2= session.createCriteria(Exchange.class,"exchange");
                c2.createAlias("exchange.country", "country");
//              c.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("cutofftime.country.id","exchange.country.id"));
                return c.list();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't get it done from hibernate using a single join as you don't have a bidirectional relationship from Country to anywhere.So I think you have to have 2 seperate joins and then filter the results in second join such that the countrrID in (country ids in first join)

Comment: it is wrong :(, you forget class Exchange, the relationship between them is Exchange.country.id = CutOffTime.country.id